# GraphQL directive params as object

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

Hi i have a problem with create directive with params which is object.

I create directive ad declaration in .graphql file,

```
directive @validate(params: ValidateParams) on FIELD_DEFINITION

input ValidateParams {
    limit: Int,
}

photos(
        limit: Int,
        sort: String,
    ): [Photo!]! @validate(params: {limit: 100})
```

I got Error

```
  Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named "ValidateParams"
```

Do you have any idea how can i create params as object? When i set limit as Int everything is ok.

Thanks!

Update

```
return new ApolloServer({
        context: ({ req: { body, headers } }) => {

            return {
                authorization: headers.authorization,
            };
        },
        debug: false,
        introspection: true,
        playground: true,
        schema: internalSchema,
        tracing: true,
        uploads: false
    });
```

```
export function buildSchema(schemaContent: string, resolvers: IResolvers, schemaDirectives: IDirectiveResolvers = {}): GraphQLSchema {
    const schema = buildFederatedSchema({ typeDefs: gql`${schemaContent}` });

    addResolveFunctionsToSchema({
        schema,
        resolvers: { JSON: GraphQLJSONObject },
        resolverValidationOptions: { requireResolversForResolveType: false, allowResolversNotInSchema: true }
    });

    if (Object.keys(schemaDirectives).length) {
        attachDirectiveResolvers(schema, schemaDirectives);
    }

    return schema;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your syntax as shown. It sounds like you've declared a type named `ValidateParams` elsewhere in your schema.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I have only one declared type named `ValidateParams`. i tried change name for this to total radom word and a have still this error ;/

Comment: Maybe you could update your question to include a small, complete schema that illustrates the issue. It would also be helpful to see how you're using this schema (i.e. if you're using it with ApolloServer, how the call to ApolloServer's constructor looks like).

Comment: Hej @DanielRearden. I added a edit part where i add code from apolloServer